# How to set correct position() of a div that is dynamically positioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an api call and displaying the info in a `div`. When I run `$(window).scrollTop($('#div').position().top)`, it returns a position of `top: 267px`. When viewing the same div in the browser, its position is actually `top: 2058px`.

Therefore, when I run the code

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf('?queryParam=') > -1) {   
    $('.button').click(function(){
      $(window).scrollTop($('#div').position().top);
    });
  }
  return;
 },false);
```

It scrolls to `top: 267px` rather than `top: 2058px` where the div is actually visible in the browser.

My theory is that because the `div` isn't static and instead is being pulled dynamically via an api call, in the event listener, it only accounts for where the div is positioned during the split second when it's being retrieved and not yet placed correctly within the browser.

Comment: You might consider posting the code you're using to get the element positions.

Comment: [`position().top`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) gives an element's scroll-position relative to its parent. To get the scroll-position relative to the window/document, use: [`offset().top`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: @myfunkyside this worked. thank you!

Comment: I thought someone would have officially answered by now. I've posted it as an answer with a little bit more explanation (I hate unanswered questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [**position().top**](https://api.jquery.com/position/) to get the `div`'s scroll-position.
But this will give you the `div`'s position relative to its parent element.
While incredibly handy in other cases, in your situation it doesn't give the desired value.

In your case you need the `div`'s position relative to the `window`, since it is the `window` that you're scrolling.
For that you need to use [**offset().top**](https://api.jquery.com/offset/), this will give you an element's position relative to the document, no matter how the element is structured on the page:

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#div').offset().top);
```